# Whereby / By which

Tags: expressions, word-usage, context

I have a doubt about the use of “whereby”. I know it can be a synonym of “by which”, but I am not sure if it can always substitute “by which”.

I am doing an essay and I wrote this:

> Will, gift, lease or sale are instances of legal instruments whereby possession can be acquired by consent or mutual consent.

Does it work here? Should I use “by which”?

Comment: 'Whereby' sounds nicely 'legalesish'. But the 'or' is incorrect.

Comment: The first _or_ is incorrect. The one at the end is OK. I'd say _whereby_ is better here because the next constituent uses a passive agent _by_ phrase.

Comment: Sounds kind of awkward to me with the second "by".  You could replace "whereby possession can be acquired" with "that allow possession to be acquired".  What is "instances of" adding?  Do you mean "examples of"?  I would also be curious as to the distinction between consent and mutual consent.

Comment: I agree with the others, whereby sounds better, and I would replace the following ‘by’ with ‘through’. Obviously if that’s not what you mean don’t do it but it removes awkwardness. And the first ‘or’ should be ‘and’.